# Materialized View for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, materialized-view

I want to know if there is some thing similar to materialized view for Oracle in SQL Server .

Any ideas ?

Comment: Try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986366/how-to-create-materialized-views-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

A view can be materialised by [creating an index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) on it. There are several [preconditions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms191432.aspx) which must be met. These may be tricky to impose on large, established applications with layered views.

Comment: Also, indexed views have an impact on the base tables they reference: you won't be able to run some types of DDL operations, like `TRUNCATE TABLE`, and any DML statement on the referenced table(s) will implicitly update the index(es) on the view in the same transaction, adding a potentially large performance penalty. IIRC, in this respect, indexed views differ from Oracle materialized views, which are manually recomputed.